# Set focus to dynamically created <input fields - use of ID, ref or name?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a list of emails, which can be extended.
I want to set focus to last item, when added.
In brief: user clicks "add" button, item gets created, item gets focus.

I have looked at "ref" which needs the variable by same name.
I want to look up items, once I reach the end, I can set focus to that item.

```
  this.myRef = React.createRef(); - this required my reference to have same name as my variable
```

Any ideas?

```
            {this.props.parentProps.AdditionalEmails.filter((x: any) => x.EmailType == 'PickUp').map((item: any, index: number) => {
              return (
                <div className={'form-group ' + (!item.IsValidated && 'has-error')} style={{ marginBottom: 5 }} data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title={item.ValMsg}>
                  <h3 className="pull-left">Additional E-mail:</h3>
                  <div className="pull-right">
                    <input
                      id={"pickup_mail_"+index} // or ref or name...?
                      className="form-control"
                      disabled={this.props.parentProps.IsApproved}
                      type="text"
                      value={item.Email}
                      onChange={e => (item.Email = e.target.value, this.forceUpdate())}
                      onBlur={() => this.validateAdditionalEmails()} />
                    <i className="icon icon-info" style={{ color: !item.IsValidated ? "#405f84" : "white" }}></i>
                  </div>
                  <div className="pull-right"><i className="icon icon-delete" style={{ color: 'red', cursor: 'pointer' }} onClick={() => this.props.updateList('AdditionalEmails', this.removedList(item))}></i></div>
                </div>
              );
            })}
```

It has a button for adding more items:

```
              <button onClick={e => this.additionalEmailClick(e, 'PickUp')}><i className="icon icon-add"></i></button>
```

Next, when an item is created, I would like for that one to have focus

```
  additionalEmailClick(event: any, emailType: string) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.updateList('AdditionalEmails', this.extendedEmailList(emailType));
    // search elements, set focus to last one
    //  GetElementByIDorREF( emailType.toLowerCase()+'_mail_'+i++++++).focus();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately I can not give you a quick working example based on class components, but basic idea is like:

1. REF is always the last item of the inputs array
2. Adding new input changes inputs array length
3. If length has been changed set focus to new ref.

In case it is not always the last one, you may store the extra state with active index, the rest logic is the same.
Here is an example with functional components use:

```
const App=()=> {
  const [inputs, setInput] = useState(["a","b"]) // the set of inputs values
  const active = useRef(null) // the ref variable
  
  // after inputs length has been changed active field get focus:
  useEffect(()=>{
    active.current.focus()
  }, [inputs.length])

  function addInput() {
    setInput([...inputs, ""])
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {inputs.map((input, idx) => {
        return <input 
                 value={input}
                 ref={idx === inputs.length-1 ? active : null}
               />)
      }
      <button onClick={addInput}>Add new input</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```